# Convert from milliseconds to microseconds and store in double in C

Tags: c, time

Hi I'm trying to convert DELAY from milliSeconds into microSeconds and store it in a double. But when I use the below code it produces the output  0.000000  On a calculator it works as the desired outcome I'm after if 500 is the DELAY is 0.500000  so I can use it with 'struct timeval'.

```
#define DELAY 500
double num = (DELAY / 1000);

printf("Num: %lf",num);
```

Comment: Do you know the rules for implicit conversion and operator selection between integer and float values?  If you use a binary operator on two integer values the operator used is an integer operator.  So the above division is integer.

Comment: It produces exactly the wrong outcome on any calculator known to me. You should be multiplying, not dividing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
(DELAY / 1000);
```

is integer arithmetic, and evaluates to zero when `DELAY` is less than 1000, change to:

```
(DELAY / 1000.0);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I can't accept your answer but when I Can I will tick it,

Answer (score 2):

This will use integer division:

```
 double num = (DELAY / 1000);
```

If you change the `1000` to a *floating constant* then you will obtain the result you want:

```
double num = (DELAY / 1000.0);
```

this works because division will perform the *usual arithmetic conversions* on it's operands which in this case will cause *DELAY* to be converted to a *double* as well.

**Note** It is probably worth noting that if you want to convert from milliSeconds into microSeconds you want to multiply by `1000` not divide.

Answer (score 0):

It does the division as integers and then converts

Try:

```
#define DELAY 500f
double num = (DELAY / 1000f);

printf("Num: %lf",num);
```